# norm from inner product

Tags: hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

I have a question in a Hilbert Spaces course as follows: 
Let $X=(x_1, x_2)$ be  vector in a vector space of all ordered pairs of complex numbers X. Can we obtain the norm defined on X by: $\|X\|=|x_1|+|x_2|$  from an inner product?

I know a norm comes from an inner product space if and only if  it satisfies the parallelogram law given by $\|X+Y\|^2+\|X-Y\|^2=2\|X\|^2+2\|Y\|^2$. However, I am quite stuck using this method. Is there another way to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't obtain this norm from an inner product. For instance, the parallelogram law doesn't hold for $X=(1,0)$ and $Y=(0,1)$:

$$
\|X+Y\|^2+\|X-Y\|^2=(|1|+|1|)^2+(|1|+|-\!1|)^2=8\ne2\|X\|^2+2\|Y\|^2\;.
$$

Comment: Thank you! that was very helpful.